# SQL Server: any work around to get NET TOTAL Sales - Refund please

Tags: sql-server

If you just create "temp" database the following code can create and add sample data into the tables.

Query is to subtract TOTAL REFUNDS FROM TOTAL SALES which results in a new column named NET TOTAL.

Show: UserID, SiteID, Name, TOTAL Sales, Total Refunds, Net Total

image linked for sample data

Thanks

### [image]

```
CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Users 
(
    UserID INT,
    SiteID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.TRANSACTIONS
(
    TransactionID int,
    UserID int,
    SiteID int,
    TransactionType varchar(10),
    TransactionDate Date,
    Amount money
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Users 
VALUES (1, 1, 'ARTHUR'), (2, 1, 'AARON'), (3, 2, 'BRETT')

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.TRANSACTIONS 
VALUES (4, 1, 1, 'SALE', GETDATE(), 120),
       (6, 1, 1, 'REFUND', GETDATE(), 120),
       (7, 2, 2, 'SALE', GETDATE(), 90),
       (9, 2, 1, 'SALE', GETDATE(), 30),
       (10, 2, 1, 'SALE', GETDATE(), 30),
       (11, 2, 1, 'SALE', GETDATE(), 30),
       (12, 2, 1, 'REFUND', GETDATE(), 30)
```

Query: This is my current query where I have tried to name it using WITH clause but no luck

```
SELECT 
    U.UserID, U.SiteID, U.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL SALES],
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL REFUNDS]
FROM 
    temp.dbo.Users AS U
INNER JOIN 
    temp.dbo.Transactions AS T ON U.UserID = T.UserID AND U.SiteID = T.SiteID
GROUP BY 
    U.UserID, U.SiteID, U.Name
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what you are looking to get help with.  As in, what is your expected output?

Comment: I had a subtract in the refunds by default however that was an easy job. I was curious to resolve it if that "-" subtract was not there. indeed i got the answer that way but I dont think that was ideal in work environment. needed how to do a postive number from a positive number where the columns are only named in the query. anyways i got the answer, and didnt know this was a way to do it,

 [NET TOTAL] = [TOTAL SALES] - [TOTAL REFUNDS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is very good, but it would be better if you provided an expected result set along with your sample data and work in progress.

There are a few approaches that will solve your problem:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) - 
SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END)
AS [NET TOTAL]
```

or

```
SUM(CASE 
   WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount 
   WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN -1 * T.Amount
   ELSE 0 
END) AS [NET TOTAL]
```

Comment: maybe because someone didn't like your answer.

Comment: @AlvaroParra It's not my answer. I just see no reason why it's been downvoted twice, and without an (constructive) reason; as it does answer the question.

Comment: look at me, that happened to me twice here, just take it easy ;)

Comment: Thanks this answer works work, with this i wont need to use WITH clause and all is sorted within a single query. But since I need Refunds total and sales total i will be doing 2 other sum cases for them and so they are presented in the results.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
with c as(
SELECT 
    U.UserID,
    COUNT(U.UserID) OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID) AS cnts,
    U.SiteID,
    U.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL SALES],
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL REFUNDS]
    -- SUM(T.Amount) AS [TOTALS]
FROM 
    temp.dbo.Users AS U
INNER JOIN 
    temp.dbo.Transactions AS T ON U.UserID = T.UserID AND U.SiteID = T.SiteID
GROUP BY 
    U.UserID, U.SiteID, U.Name
)
select *
      ,[NET TOTAL] = [TOTAL SALES] - [TOTAL REFUNDS]
from c
```

also you can do this

```
SELECT 
    U.UserID,
    COUNT(U.UserID) OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID) AS cnts,
    U.SiteID,
    U.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL SALES],
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL REFUNDS],
    -- SUM(T.Amount) AS [TOTALS]
     SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'SALE' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) 
    - SUM(CASE WHEN T.TransactionType = 'REFUND' THEN T.Amount ELSE 0 END) as [NET TOTAL]
FROM 
    temp.dbo.Users AS U
INNER JOIN 
    temp.dbo.Transactions AS T ON U.UserID = T.UserID AND U.SiteID = T.SiteID
GROUP BY 
    U.UserID, U.SiteID, U.Name
```